# Git: branched off but parent branch has changed

Tags: git, version-control, merge

Here is my scenario:

`git checkout master`

`git pull`

Now `master` is up to date.

We create a new branch and switch to it:

`git branch test`

`git checkout test`

*As of this point, `test` and `master` should be identical, with `test` being a local branch not visible to `remote/origin`.* (Correct me if this is wrong, but I see no reason why it should be)

Now, somewhere along the way, `master` is merged with additional branches that affect files that you are working on locally in `test`. My question is:

**Aside from `git stash`ing the changes so far, deleting the local `test` branch, and branching off from `master` *again*, what is the best way to merge the new changes from `master` into the local `test` branch?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already mentioned your could merge `master` into `test` by

```
git checkout test
git merge master
```

which will collect the changes on `master` branch and apply them in one merge commit on `test`.

Instead you could also run `git rebase master test` which will reapply the commits in `test` onto the new `master` and give you a linear history.